# How to analyze this MOSFET H-bridge circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, h-bridge, homework, nmos, pmos

In my university electronics course project, I am asked to analyze an H-bridge circuit.  It is a simple H-bridge in which the motor is represented with a 37 ohm resistor and thus has no diodes.

[image: schematic]

The circuit in the image is a particular equivalent for an H-bridge circuit;
I got this circuit once I determined the gate voltage of each of the four MOSFETs, and found which MOSFETs are ON and which are OFF. After that, I determined the current path which gave me this equivalent circuit.

Given that:

1. the current passing the PMOS equals the current passing the NMOS
2. we can apply Ohm's law on the resistor
3. the MOSFETs are essentially being used as switches, so they are in Triode mode
4. channel length modulation is neglected
5. for NMOS \$I_D = kn[V_DS(V_OV) - \frac{V_DS^2}{2}]\$
6. \$|V_tn| = |V_tp| = 3V\$

Through my analysis, I got three equations with three unknowns given:

\$-0.05(V_Dp)^2 + 0.3V_Dp - I_D = 0.112\$

\$-0.05 (V_Dn)^2 + 0.6V_Dn - I_D = 0\$

\$V_Dp - V_Dn = 37I_D\$

I then tried to plug the third equation into the first two, and I got:

\$V_Dn = 1.85(V_Dp)^2 - 10.1V_Dp + 4.144\$

\$V_Dp = -1.85(V_Dn)^2 + 23.2V_Dn\$

How can I solve it from here? Is my methodology right?